# Reason for lpm_constant to exist

Tags: vhdl, verilog, fpga, intel-fpga

I'm currently analyzing a given FPGA Verilog program and I stumbled upon the **lpm_constant** IP-Core, provided by Altera.
The only thing it does is to provide a constant value to a bus.
My Question is, why one should use this IP-Core, instead of a wire with constant value, or a reg with initialization in initial block, or reset cycle.
I also don't see the point of the reason being either to improve performance (Fitter should take care of this anyways, regardless of implementation) or compatibility with other designs (the language Verilog/VHDL is standardized, so why would this be an issue).
Thanks for clarification.

Comment: This is a legacy block and Altera now even recommends to use `constant `. This is from the time where "building block-based development" was the ideal. Due to the extra entity, parsing will actually be slower. But overall the impact will not be large. By the way, these kind of building blocks are still used by GUI design tools, like xilinx IP-integrator.

Answer (score 0):

One can use the In-System Memory Content editor to change the value of the "constant" at design run time, to help in debug and testing of the design. We lose this capability if we hard code a value in RTL.

Answer (score -1):

As @JHBonarius said the only reason to use **lpm_constant** (Altera Megafunction) if you describe your project in a schematic way, i.e. use Block Design File (*.bdf). If you use HDL-like approach use CONSTANT to make code CAD Tools independent.